# How do i properly configure a nested router (react-router-dom)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My site will have pages that will need a header and some pages without.

For example, email verification pages, oauth pages, etc won't need a header.

But for the application itself I will need a header which contains a search bar, links, logos, etc.

I'm trying to split these via react router

i currently have this parent router

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/emailverfication">
            <Emailverification />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/discordauth">
            <DiscordOauthPortal />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
            <Home />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

In `Home` I have yet another router

```
<Container>
    <Header>
        <Link to="/games">Games</Link>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <SearchBar/>
        <AuthLinks/>
    </Header>
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route  path="/games">
                <Games/>
            </Route>
            <Route  path="/">
                <Main />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
</Container>
```

accessing the paths via manually typing url will reach desired path

however clicking the links will not.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `<Router>` and only using and only keeping the `<Switch>` block did the trick.
so the child component looks like this

```
<Container>
    <Header>
        <Link to="/games">Games</Link>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <SearchBar/>
        <AuthLinks/>
    </Header>
    <Switch>
        <Route  path="/games">
            <Games/>
        </Route>
        <Route  path="/">
            <Main />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
</Container>
```